# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f Doesn't Recognise Query Strings

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following to pass file requests straight through to their relevant files when they exist on the server using the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^. - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^. - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^. script.php [L,QSA]
```

This works great for standard URLs such as:

```
/process.php
/delete.php
```

But when I add a query string it fails to match so:

```
/process.php?testing=1
```

fails to match and gets processed by script.php

Comment: That should not happen. I note that you use `%{REQUEST_URI}` in the title, but `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` in your question.

Comment: Hi Gerben, it turns out that it doesn't... After hours and hours of going through the code I came to the conclusion that I was missing something with htaccess so thought I'd ask the wider community. You response prompted me to look again at my code... It's always something simple, the script validates the URL and throws a 404 if it doesn't match.
Thanks for your time, and indeed help.